# Creating an array from other arrays

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I'm pulling data from a table in two different queries, and I am trying to compare the date field from both results. When the date is equal I want to add the two ending balances from each query together and put the results into a new array. The problem I am having is `on line 59`, The error I get is 
 `Notice: Undefined offset`.

This is what I have:

```
 include "../sqlConnect.php";

 mysqli_set_charset($dbScrap, 'utf8');
 $dataArray[] = array();
$dateArray[] = array();
$balanceArray[] = array();

//Smaller
$query = "SELECT Account, Date ,SUM(EndingBalance) AS 'Month_Total' FROM gl_period_posting_history
    INNER JOIN gl_account
      ON gl_period_posting_history.AccountKey = gl_account.AccountKey
  Where gl_account.Account= '5010-15-0000' AND  FiscalYear > 2012
  GROUP BY Account, Date";

$result = mysqli_query( $dbScrap, $query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . 
mysqli_error($dbScrap));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

$EndingBalance15 = $row['Month_Total'];
$Date15 = $row['Date'];

$dateArray[] = array(
    'Date' => $Date15
);

$balanceArray[] = array(
    'EndingBalance' => $EndingBalance15
);


}


\\Bigger
    $query1 = "SELECT Account, Date ,SUM(EndingBalance) AS 'Month_Total' FROM gl_period_posting_history
    INNER JOIN gl_account
      ON gl_period_posting_history.AccountKey = gl_account.AccountKey
  Where gl_account.Account ='5010-08-0000' AND  FiscalYear > 2012
  GROUP BY Account, Date";

 $result = mysqli_query( $dbScrap,$query1) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysqli_error($dbScrap));
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

$Date08 = $row['Date'];
$EndingBalance08 = $row['Month_Total'];

for($i = 0; $i < $dateArray; $i++){
        if($Date08 == $dateArray[$i]) {
            $message = "Date Equal";
            $EndingBalance = $EndingBalance08 + $balanceArray[$i];
            $Date = $Date08;
        }else{
            $message = "Date Not Equal";
            $Date = $Date08;
            $EndingBalance = $EndingBalance08;
        }
    }
    $dataArray[] = array(

        'EndingBalance' => $EndingBalance,
        'Date' => $Date,
        'Message' => $message
    );
 }
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($dataArray);
 //echo json_encode($dataArray);
 echo "</pre>";

 $result->close();
 /* close connection */
 $dbScrap->close();
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is your line 59?

Comment: You're attempting to loop through `$dateArray` but at the end of the loop you append another element. This means the loop will never exit.

Comment: @swapgs  if($Date08 == $dateArray[$i]) is line 59

Comment: `$Date08` is a string, `$dateArray[$i]` is an array. They will never be equal.

Comment: It looks like you shouldn't be appending arrays in your first while loop. Just use `$dateArray[] = $Date15;` and `$balanceArray[] = $EndingBalance15;`.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Could I convert that array element index to a string, then to an int? -Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need to explicitly convert string to int. PHP will convert it automatically based on context. Try eliminating the extra array layer when you're building `$dateArray` as I suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thank you. That worked, but only for the last index. The rest don't equal, but I know there are more then one equal dates.

Comment: Is Date unique for each Account? You could use Date as the key if that's the case.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Date is not unique, but I am pulling it from the database and grouping them by the date.

Comment: Oops, I missed that. So Date will definitely be unique in the results, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop where you fetch results from your first query, use the date from each row as the key in  `$balanceArray`, like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $EndingBalance15 = $row['Month_Total'];
    $Date15 = $row['Date'];

    $balanceArray[$Date15] = $EndingBalance15;
}
```

Then in the loop where you fetch results from your second query, you can use `isset` to check if that date exists in the results from the first query, like this.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $Date08 = $row['Date'];
    $EndingBalance08 = $row['Month_Total'];

    if (isset($balanceArray[$Date08])) {
        $message = "Date Equal";
        $EndingBalance = $EndingBalance08 + $balanceArray[$Date08];
    } else {
        $message = "Date Not Equal";
        $EndingBalance = $EndingBalance08;
    }
    $dataArray[] = array(
        'EndingBalance' => $EndingBalance,
        'Date' => $Date08,
        'Message' => $message
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in for loop, correction:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($dateArray); $i++){
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked, but the ending balances are not adding together

Comment: That just solves one specific error. There are other problems.

Comment: if($Date08 == $dateArray[$i])  should be if($Date08 == $dateArray[$i]['Date'])

Comment: @T.AKROUT I got the following error 'Illegal string offset 'Date' '

Comment: You have the error because you removed 
$dateArray[] = array(
    'Date' => $Date15
); and you replaced it by 
$dateArray[] = $Date15, now you don't have to change any thing